# bash completion for list of possible values of an environment variable

Tags: bash-completion

Consider an environment variable that can take a list of arbitrary possible meaningful values. For an example of such an environment variable consider `AWS_PROFILE`. The list of possible values can be easily computed by some command, e. g. `aws configure list-profiles`. Is there any way I can write a custom completion such as whenever I type

```
$ AWS_PROFILE=<TAB>
$ AWS_PROFILE=partial-profile-nam<TAB>
```

or

```
$ export AWS_PROFILE=<TAB>
$ export AWS_PROFILE=partial-profile-nam<TAB>
```

I can get the completion function run and suggest the list of possible values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a rough example:

```bash
# cat compspec
_aws_profiles()
{
    echo {foo,bar}-profile-{1,2}
}

_export_comp()
{
    local cur=$2
    local profiles=$( _aws_profiles )

    if [[ $COMP_LINE == *' AWS_PROFILE='* ]]; then
        COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W "$profiles" -- "$cur" ) )
        return
    fi
}

complete -F _export_comp -o default -o bashdefault export
```

```
$ source ./compspec
$ export AWS_PROFILE=<TAB><TAB>
bar-profile-1  bar-profile-2  foo-profile-1  foo-profile-2
$ export AWS_PROFILE=f
$ export AWS_PROFILE=f<TAB>
$ export AWS_PROFILE=foo-profile-
$ export AWS_PROFILE=foo-profile-<TAB><TAB>
foo-profile-1  foo-profile-2
```

The above would not work for `$ AWS_PROFILE=<TAB>`. As a workaround you can define an alias which expands to nothing:

```bash
alias %=''
complete -F _export_comp -o default -o bashdefault %
```

Then you can

```
$ % AWS_PROFILE=<TAB><TAB>
bar-profile-1  bar-profile-2  foo-profile-1  foo-profile-2
```

Comment: Is it just not possible to have plain `AWS_PROFILE=<TAB>` complete?

Comment: no, as far as i know.

Comment: This, unfortunately, has a side effect of shadowing other completions for `export`, such as completing environment variable names. For example `$ export PA<TAB>` would complete to `$ export PATH=` without this loaded. Any chance we can have both this and whatever default completions there were before together?

Comment: what's your output of `complete -p export` without loading my script?

Comment: `-bash: complete: export: no completion specification`

Comment: `$ export PA<TAB>` does not work for me with an empty bashrc (`bash --norc`).

Comment: you can try adding `else COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -v -- "$cur" ) )` to the `if` block